# Better an helper class with only static methods or class instance with same helper methods

Tags: java, performance, compilation

I have a question related to performance and how the compiler works in Java.

If I have a class with no state at all like

```
public class Helper {

  public String helperMethod(String text) {
     ....
     return value; 
  }
}
```

instead of doing

```
public class StaticHelper {

  public static String helperMethod(String text) {
     ....
     return value; 
  }
}
```

And then I do several call of type

```
new Helper().helperMethod("bla");
```

will the compiler somehow optimize the object creation or should I expect an overhead (minimal, I suppose) on the garbage collector and allocated memory?

Otherwise I should do `StaticHelper.helperMethod("bla")`, but this will prevent me to use a fluent interface, that I'd prefer.

Comment: [Escape analysis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis) avoids allocating the object in heap

Comment: Static  makes the method belong to the class not a instance. Any method that does not depend on the objects state should be static, it is cheaper in memory and tells anyone who uses it that its not dependant on the objects state. As a refrence you can check Files or Arrays class form java library. From yojr example creating an instance to call a method that does not depend on the objects state is bad design.

Comment: What's the point of a fluent interface if you don't have any state?

Comment: @JosephThomson semantic mainly, e.g. I want to group utility methods by topic that are put under a static class

Comment: @VinceEmigh interesting. Can you elaborate an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in these cases except the one moment.
Nested class (static inner class) in Java doesn't have a reference to the Outer class, but the Inner class has a reference to the Outer. You can have problems with performance because JVM can't GC the Outer class if you have a reference to the Inner Class in your code.